# Simple AI method to make sprite follow player using car physics?

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, coordinates, game-physics, radians

I am making a top-down car battling game using JavaScript. I need a simple method to make the enemy car follow the player around the map based on the players coordinates. The hard part for me is that I need to make sure the enemy car uses the same turning physics as the player.

What I am looking for is help creating a simple movement formula that will decide when to move forward/backwards and/or when to rotate the enemy in order to bring it closer to the player.

I have tried many various "if enemy.x >player.x .." but I am thinking this is going to require a math function beyond simple logic, maybe something utilizing slope intercept or something but I don't have an idea how to implement

```
//this is the actual movement algorithm I am using
this.move=function(){
this.angle += this.rotation * Math.PI / 180;
this.nextX = this.x + this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
this.nextY = this.y - this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle

//This is how I am moving the player character atm
 if(LEFT) { 
        this.rotation = -1;
    }else if(RIGHT) {
        this.rotation = 1;   
    }else {this.rotation = 0;}

    if(UP && !BOOST) { 
        this.speed = 1;
    }else if(DOWN) {
        this.speed = -1;   
    }else if(UP && BOOST) {
        this.speed = 4;   
    }else {this.speed = 0;}
```